# How to implement homomorphic multiplication for Elgamal?

Tags: implementation, homomorphic-encryption, elgamal-encryption

I want to add the homomorphic property to Elgamal in [libgcrypt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/).

This is the core code I added to the library.

```
static void 
do_homo_mul (gcry_mpi_t a, gcry_mpi_t b, gcry_mpi_t data1_a, gcry_mpi_t data1_b, gcry_mpi_t data2_a, gcry_mpi_t data2_b, ELG_public_key *pkey)
{
  mpi_normalize (data1_a);
  mpi_normalize (data1_b);
  mpi_normalize (data2_a);
  mpi_normalize (data2_b);

  mpi_mulm (a, data1_a, data2_a, pkey->p);
  mpi_mulm (b, data1_b, data2_b, pkey->p);
}
```

But I cannot get the right result. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you explain the parameters and the variables? Maybe comment each line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(R_1,c_1)=(g^{r_1}, A^{r_1}m_1)$ and $(R_2,c_2)=(g^{r_2},A^{r_2}m_2)$ are ciphertexts (with respect to the same public key $A$) corresponding to two messages $m_1$ and $m_2$, then
$$(R_1R_2,c_1c_2)=(g^{r_1+r_2},A^{r_1+r_2}m_1m_2)$$
is an encryption of the message $m_1m_2$ (note that the calculations are performed in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, that is, modulo $p$).

Assuming that `mpi_mulm(r, x, y, m)` denotes the computation $r=xy\bmod m$ (which quick inspection of the GnuPG source code seems to confirm), this implies that `(a, b)` should indeed decrypt to the product of the plaintexts corresponding to `(data1_a, data1_b)` and `(data2_a, data2_b)`.

This, in turn, likely means your correctness checks are flawed. If you care to post some example data and/or code, I can take a further look at the problem.